# Localizable User Controls

Tags: visual-studio-2008, localization, windows-forms-designer

If I have a form that is localized and has User Controls that are localized, how I can I view the form and the controls in the language specified in the VS Properties?

Right now when I change the language, all my controls that are not part a user control adjust appropriately, but my user controls do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to localize each user control individually when designing it in the designer. Then you can set the property Localizable on the user control to true and choose your language. Unfortunately the surrounding Form does not escalate these two properties to its user controls when the Form is designed. That is a problem, but only at design time. At runtime however it will work and your user controls should show the correctly localized values.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure: has the user control Localizable=true? It should probably not define a language for its own, to make it use the language set on the parent.