# Localized UserControl at Design Time

Tags: winforms, user-controls

I build an UserControl which is localizable. The UserControl's Localizable Property is set to true and I have already a localized label on this control. I add this control to a Form. This Form's Localizable Property is also set to true.
At runtime this label is correct localized. But I like to have also a preview of this localized UserControl at Design Time when I switch the Form's Language Property.

Is it possible to have a preview of this localized UserControl at Design Time? If yes, how?

Comment: Read the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627520/localizable-user-controls